# React Native: обновление экрана с данными при загрузке БД - как?

Tags: react-native, expo

Всем здравствуйте!
Впервые делаю приложение на React Native и не соображу, как сделать следующее (использую модуль @react-navigation для роутинга между экранами): загружаю БД на одном экране и хочу, чтобы полученные данные отобразились на другом (второй экран перерендерился с новыми данными). Данные в БД загружаются успешно, но не отображаются до релога приложения, т.е. повторного рендера не происходит. Если его закрыть и открыть заново, или пересобрать, всё отображается. Можно как-то принудительно вызвать повторный рендер? Из идей только принудительная повторная загрузка всего приложения, но это ресурсозатратно и не оправдано. UseContext тоже так себе идея. В общем, я в тупике и буду благодарна помощи.
P.S. использую Expo.

Answer (score 0):

В документации @react-navigation есть замечательный раздел, под названием Passing parameters to routes. Там сказано, что мы можем передавать параметры на целевой экран вместе с методом navigate. Конструкция имеет следующий вид: `navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })` .
То есть, вы дополнительных параметрах вы указываете список полей, которые хотите передать на другой экран. Дальше нужно только принять эти параметры на другом экране.

```
function AnotherScreen({ route, navigation }) {
 const { param1, otherParam...n } = route.params;
 return param1
};
```

Далее используйте эти параметры так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Я думала над этим вариантом, но в этом случае он мне не подходил, нашла альтернативный. Спасибо за уделённое время.

Answer (score 0):

Задала вопрос и вскорости нашла на него ответ: в моем случае помог useIsFocused из react-navigation.